# Calculating the average in a Loop Java

Tags: java

I just found that when I calculate the average for the second user, I get a different result. For example, if I add this number for the first user 10,10,10,20,20. I get 14.0 which is correct. But when I enter the same number for the second user I get 28.0? any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class midterm 
{
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sum = 0;
    double average=0;
    int count = 0;
    int salary_annually = 0;

    for(int employee =1; employee <= 2; employee++)
    {
      System.out.println("Employee: " + employee);

      for(int year=1; year <= 5; year++)
      {   
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Salary for Year: "  + year);
        salary_annually = kb.nextInt();

        sum += salary_annually  ;
        average = (sum) / 5.0; 

        if (min >= salary_annually) 
        { 
          min = salary_annually;
        } 

        if (max <=salary_annually) 
        { 
          max = salary_annually;
        } 
      }

      System.out.println("The average is " + average);
      System.out.println("The higher number  " + max);
      System.out.println("The the lowest number " + min);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum = 0; // this before 2nd loop
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // these too.
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int year=1; year <= 5; year++)
{
   .
   .
   .
}
average = (sum) / 5.0; // this after 2nd loop
```

In your solution you are calculating average 5 times inside the loop! and you only get advantage from the fifth time! must be after the loop. `average = (sum) / 5.0;` after the loop.

Comment: for(int employee =1; employee <= 2; employee++)
        {
        System.out.println("Employee: " + employee);
        sum = 0; // this before 2nd loop
        average = (sum) / 5.0; // this after 2nd loop


        
             for(int year=1; year <= 5; year++)
             {   
                I tried this, but I am getting the average number is zero? what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You need to zero `sum` at the end of the loop. As it is, now it just keeps increasing and increasing as the old value is kept in memory, when coming to the next iteration.

Comment: You're zeroing it inside the same loop where you count the sum. That won't work. Just zero it outside that loop. Either before you enter it or after it's finished.